# Write only last element to XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to write my datas that come from database to an xml file.There are 5 data.The problem is JAXB is writing only last data to XML file.Here is my codes;

```
public void createXmlFile() {
    String path = Labels.getLabel("zk.file.xmlfilepath");
    Kitap k = new Kitap();
    File xmlFile = new File(path);

    try {
        if (xmlFile.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("Kitaplar.xml file created.");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Kitaplar.xml file can't created!");
        }

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Kitap.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < kitapList.size(); i++) {
            k.setKitapId(kitapList.get(i).getKitapId());
            k.setKitapad(kitapList.get(i).getKitapad());
            k.setYazarad(kitapList.get(i).getYazarad());
            k.setKitapdurum(kitapList.get(i).getKitapdurum());
            k.setKitaptur(kitapList.get(i).getKitaptur());
            k.setKitapImage(kitapList.get(i).getKitapimage());

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(k, xmlFile);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(k, System.out);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Kitap.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Kitap {

private int kitapId;
private String kitapad;
private String yazarad;
private String kitaptur;
private String kitapdurum;
private byte[] kitapImage;

public int getKitapId() {
    return kitapId;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setKitapId(int kitapId) {
    this.kitapId = kitapId;
}

public String getKitapad() {
    return kitapad;
}

@XmlElement
public void setKitapad(String kitapad) {
    this.kitapad = kitapad;
}

public String getYazarad() {
    return yazarad;
}

@XmlElement
public void setYazarad(String yazarad) {
    this.yazarad = yazarad;
}

public String getKitaptur() {
    return kitaptur;
}

@XmlElement
public void setKitaptur(String kitaptur) {
    this.kitaptur = kitaptur;
}

public String getKitapdurum() {
    return kitapdurum;
}

@XmlElement
public void setKitapdurum(String kitapdurum) {
    this.kitapdurum = kitapdurum;
}

public byte[] getKitapImage() {
    return kitapImage;
}

@XmlElement
public void setKitapImage(byte[] kitapImage) {
    this.kitapImage = kitapImage;
}
```

}

What is the wrong in my codes?Why only the last element is writing on xml file?

Comment: Have you already debugged and stopped it in the middle? Maybe the file is always overwritten...

Answer (score 1):

Please read the spec of the JAXB marshaller: https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.File%29

More to the point:

```
File to be written. If this file already exists, it will be overwritten.
```

You are marshalling inside the loop so basically you are overwriting the file everytime with the last element.

One solution is to make a wrapper object that has a list of `Kitap` objects and marshal said wrapper object.

Comment: Or you serialize to an `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter` and keep that file open between calls to `marshal` (although the output will not be valid XML as the `<?xml` declaration will be repeated.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It will also not be valid as it will have multiple root tags

Comment: I didn't understand the solution.Is there any code example?